# What does update actually do?

Tags: craft3, updates

Upon [updating](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/updating.html#updating-from-the-terminal) CraftCMS via CP > Utilities or Terminal, does this update only the vendor folder? Or does it also change structure in the DB and other files outside the vendor?

Answer (score 1):

DB and eventually others files are updated in the first request after the Update.